# PHP Soapclient consume .NET WSDL

Tags: php, web-services, wsdl, soap-client

I have recently been struggling sending data through a WSDL webservice, which seems to be written by C#, and running on a WINDOWS.

https://occurrences.caa.govt.nz/Test/CAA.Part12Interface.CaptureService.CaptureService.svc

Firts off... I had to resolve the WINS URL to IP address... because it's not important in this question, so I skip how that was solved. So just simply replace caa-ws-01 with occurrences.caa.govt.nz

Below are the WSDL itself and XSD that defines complexTypes

WSDL

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<wsdl:definitions targetNamespace="http://www.caa.govt.nz/CAA.Part12Interface.CaptureService" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:wsx="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/mex" xmlns:wsa10="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" xmlns:tns="http://www.caa.govt.nz/CAA.Part12Interface.CaptureService" xmlns:soap12="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy" xmlns:wsap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing/policy" xmlns:msc="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/12/wsdl/contract" xmlns:wsa="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing" xmlns:wsam="http://www.w3.org/2007/05/addressing/metadata" xmlns:wsaw="http://www.w3.org/2006/05/addressing/wsdl" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
  <wsdl:types>
    <xsd:schema targetNamespace="http://www.caa.govt.nz/CAA.Part12Interface.CaptureService/Imports">
      <xsd:import schemaLocation="https://caa-ws-01/Test/CAA.Part12Interface.CaptureService.CaptureService.svc?xsd=xsd0" namespace="http://www.caa.govt.nz/CAA.Part12Interface.CaptureService"/>
      <xsd:import schemaLocation="https://caa-ws-01/Test/CAA.Part12Interface.CaptureService.CaptureService.svc?xsd=xsd1" namespace="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/"/>
    </xsd:schema>
  </wsdl:types>
  <wsdl:message name="ICaptureService_SubmitData_InputMessage">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:SubmitData"/>
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="ICaptureService_SubmitData_OutputMessage">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:SubmitDataResponse"/>
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="ICaptureService_SubmitData_CaptureServiceFaultFault_FaultMessage">
    <wsdl:part name="detail" element="tns:CaptureServiceFault"/>
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="ICaptureService_SubmitMobileData_InputMessage">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:SubmitMobileData"/>
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="ICaptureService_SubmitMobileData_OutputMessage">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:SubmitMobileDataResponse"/>
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="ICaptureService_SubmitMobileData_CaptureServiceFaultFault_FaultMessage">
    <wsdl:part name="detail" element="tns:CaptureServiceFault"/>
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:portType name="ICaptureService">
    <wsdl:operation name="SubmitData">
      <wsdl:input wsaw:Action="http://www.caa.govt.nz/CAA.Part12Interface.CaptureService/ICaptureService/SubmitData" message="tns:ICaptureService_SubmitData_InputMessage"/>
      <wsdl:output wsaw:Action="http://www.caa.govt.nz/CAA.Part12Interface.CaptureService/ICaptureService/SubmitDataResponse" message="tns:ICaptureService_SubmitData_OutputMessage"/>
      <wsdl:fault wsaw:Action="http://www.caa.govt.nz/CAA.Part12Interface.CaptureService/ICaptureService/SubmitDataCaptureServiceFaultFault" name="CaptureServiceFaultFault" message="tns:ICaptureService_SubmitData_CaptureServiceFaultFault_FaultMessage"/>
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="SubmitMobileData">
      <wsdl:input wsaw:Action="http://www.caa.govt.nz/CAA.Part12Interface.CaptureService/ICaptureService/SubmitMobileData" message="tns:ICaptureService_SubmitMobileData_InputMessage"/>
      <wsdl:output wsaw:Action="http://www.caa.govt.nz/CAA.Part12Interface.CaptureService/ICaptureService/SubmitMobileDataResponse" message="tns:ICaptureService_SubmitMobileData_OutputMessage"/>
      <wsdl:fault wsaw:Action="http://www.caa.govt.nz/CAA.Part12Interface.CaptureService/ICaptureService/SubmitMobileDataCaptureServiceFaultFault" name="CaptureServiceFaultFault" message="tns:ICaptureService_SubmitMobileData_CaptureServiceFaultFault_FaultMessage"/>
    </wsdl:operation>
  </wsdl:portType>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

XSD:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://www.caa.govt.nz/CAA.Part12Interface.CaptureService" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:tns="http://www.caa.govt.nz/CAA.Part12Interface.CaptureService">
  <xs:element name="SubmitData">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="data" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:element name="SubmitDataResponse">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence/>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:complexType name="CaptureServiceFault">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="DeveloperMessage" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="UserMessage" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:element name="CaptureServiceFault" nillable="true" type="tns:CaptureServiceFault"/>
  <xs:element name="SubmitMobileData">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="data" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:element name="SubmitMobileDataResponse">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence/>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

I am using PHP SoapClient on a Ubuntu server to test the web service, and I am able to __getFunctions() and __getTypes(), however, when I tried to call one of the functions: SubmitData, it returns me:

```
object(SoapFault)#5 (9) {
  ["message":protected]=>
  string(21) "Internal Server Error"
  ["string":"Exception":private]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["code":protected]=>
  int(0)
  ["file":protected]=>
  string(36) "[PATH_TO_FOLDER]/index.php"
  ["line":protected]=>
  int(36)
  ["trace":"Exception":private]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    array(4) {
      ["function"]=>
      string(11) "__doRequest"
      ["class"]=>
      string(10) "SoapClient"
      ["type"]=>
      string(2) "->"
      ["args"]=>
      array(5) {
        [0]=>
        string(12609) "<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<env:Envelope xmlns:env="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:ns1="http://www.caa.govt.nz/CAA.Part12Interface.CaptureService"><env:Body><ns1:data><?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ClientOccurrence 
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://caa.govt.nz/Schema/Occurrence_1_0 ../Schema/Occurrence_1_0.xsd" 
  xmlns="http://caa.govt.nz/Schema/Occurrence_1_0" 
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  //...
</ClientOccurrence>
</ns1:data>"
          }
        }
      }
    }
    [2]=>
    array(6) {
      ["file"]=>
      string(36) "[PATH_TO_FOLDER]/index.php"
      ["line"]=>
      int(36)
      ["function"]=>
      string(10) "SubmitData"
      ["class"]=>
      string(10) "SoapClient"
      ["type"]=>
      string(2) "->"
      ["args"]=>
      array(1) {
        [0]=>
        object(SoapVar)#4 (2) {
          ["enc_type"]=>
          int(147)
          ["enc_value"]=>
          string(12397) "<ns1:data><?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ClientOccurrence 
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://caa.govt.nz/Schema/Occurrence_1_0 ../Schema/Occurrence_1_0.xsd" 
  xmlns="http://caa.govt.nz/Schema/Occurrence_1_0" 
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  //...
</ClientOccurrence>
</ns1:data>"
        }
      }
    }
  }
  ["previous":"Exception":private]=>
  NULL
  ["faultstring"]=>
  string(21) "Internal Server Error"
  ["faultcode"]=>
  string(4) "HTTP"
}
```

Below is my code:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');

try {
    $client = new SoapClient('https://occurrences.caa.govt.nz/Test/CAA.Part12Interface.CaptureService.CaptureService.svc?wsdl',array('soap_version'=>SOAP_1_2,'exceptions'=>FALSE,'trace'=>1,'cache_wsdl' => WSDL_CACHE_NONE));

    $fn = '../occurences/5/182/1437104659.xml';
    $fh = fopen($fn,'r');
    if (FALSE === $fh) {
        exit("Failed to open stream to URL");
    }
    $contents = fread($fh,filesize($fn));

    $SubmitData = new stdClass();
    //$SubmitData->data = $contents; //the parameter this function takes is a XML string. But, using this line, will convert the '<' and '>' in $contents into &lt; and &gt;, so I use the line below instead
    $SubmitData->data = new SoapVar('<ns1:data>'.$contents.'</ns1:data>', XSD_ANYXML);
    $response = $client->SubmitData($SubmitData);
    print '<pre>';
    if (is_soap_fault($response)) {
        var_dump($response);
    }else{

    }

}catch(Exception $e) {
    var_dump($response);
}
?>
```

I have searched the internet, and it says if the server returns internal server error, it means the server doesn't like the parameter that I submit. I am now confused, and not sure what I did wrong.

I turned to ask the client's IT support, yet not much help, but only gave me a .exe file (come with .config and .dll) that only works on Windows platform, .NET Framework environment. They claim this exe "calling exactly the same function, with the same XML data", and then showed me the sample code in C#:

```
 [TestClass]
    public class UnitTest1
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void TestMethod1()
        {
            var target = new CaptureServiceClient();
            target.Open();
            const string data = [SOME_XML_STRING];
            target.SubmitMobileData(data);
            target.Close();
        }
    }
```

So, in order to diagnose the place it might go wrong, I did:

1. I tried a different web service (http://www.webservicex.com/globalweather.asmx?wsdl), with similar code, and it works (although I am not passing XML strings as the parameters) -- code works, our server SOAP module is running OK
2. Because the client also provides us a '.exe' file for testing on Windows platform, I tried it with the same XML data, and it worked. -- so I assume the data is fine, and their WSDL service is running OK as well? Although in the sample code they tossed the parameter in as a type of string (whereas in PHP soapclient I have to wrap it in an object..)
3. I tried to call __getLastRequest(), it returns me the SOAP envelope and its content, so I assume the SOAP server did receive my request.

Now I am out of ideas -- I am new to SOAP, and haven't done PHP soapclient and .NET webservice before. Can somebody who is experienced in this domain give a hand?

Comment: At this stage, I just want to know whether the fault is in my code, or is on the other side of the fence